# How to use regexp to substring number/number string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regexp to substring a pattern like digit/digit + "discussion"
example:

> "this pull request has 08/09 discussions"

I would like to get

> 09/09

I'm trying:

```
  var regex = /\d+\/\d+/g
  var matched = body.match(regex)
```

I need to consider "discussions" after 08/09 to check if its the string that I'm looking for.

Comment: `var regex = /\d+\/\d+(?=\s*discussion)/`

Comment: regex101.com is your friend

Comment: You have a typo there, or you really want to get `09/09`  from `this pull request has 08/09 discussions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead

```
\d+\/\d+(?=\s*discussions)
```

[image]

```js
let str = "this pull request has 08/09 discussions 0/09"
var regex = /\d+\/\d+(?=\s*discussions)/g
var matched = str.match(regex)

console.log(matched)
```